# How can I perform algebra such as apple + apple = 2 apple?

Tags: python, algebra

Is its possible to define an algebra for string objects?
For example:

- apple + apple = 2 apple
- apple + orange = orange + apple
- apple + 3.5 apple = 4.5 apple

Are there built-in functions that could do that? Is the creation of a class structure necessary?

Comment: Looks like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) could work for this.

Comment: You mean you want to build monoids and monads in Python? Functional programming?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu no, I don't think the OP is referring to anything like that, it sounds like they want a computer algebra system.

Comment: No, there are no built-in functions for this. An no, a class structure is *never really necessary to accomplish anything*. However, often, it is a useful way to organize your code. In any case, what you are describing isn't strings. It *sounds* like you want a computer algebra system, something that manipulates symbols using mathematics. `sympy` is a popular library for this sort of thing in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`SymPy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to define symbolic variables for this type of algebra.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> apple = symbols('apple')
>>> orange = symbols('orange')
>>> apple + apple
2*apple
>>> apple + orange
apple + orange
>>> apple + 3.5 * apple
4.5*apple
```

Comment: CoryKramer, thank you so much for your quick response and excellent solution!